# How to print the idea of a whitespace

Tags: java, location, whitespace

I have a problem that says to write a code that prints the location of any space for any 2-character string passCode in java. I know I have to first make the string into an array so that an index of either 0 or 1 can be printed as the location but I'm not sure how. Any suggestions?

Comment: you dont have to convert it to array, there is a method `String#indexOf()` that you can use

Answer (score 0):

First things first, all Strings are already arrays (of chars), therefore any conversion thereof is unnecessary. I am at this point, not entirely sure what it is that you mean by your question. From what I understand, you have a program, that will be passed a two character long string, and you must decide whether it is the first or second spot. Here is a bit of something:

```
/* @return location of space in a string of length two, or -1 if none found */
// pre-condition: first, second, or no char is a space
public int findSpace(String str) {
    return (str.charAt(0)==' ')?0:(str.charAt(1)==' ')?1:-1;
}
```

Comment: how if the string value is a single character? to be safe, use `return str.indexOf(' ');`

Comment: String won't be a single character, that's what the pre-condition says. If you want to change the pre-condition, then you'll have to change the code (obviously).